# Is there a word for words about words?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are several words for types of words. For example, a "synonym" is a word for words with similar meanings, "demonym" is the word for a word describing a resident of an area, and "noun" is the word for a word for a thing.

Just out of curiosity, is there a word for these words?

Comment: @ermanen That's not what I mean. I'm referring to words that reference words of a specific purpose. EDIT: The closest thing I can think of is "parts of speech", but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: You might be looking for *hypernym*.

Comment: There's the recently (?) coined term "nymonym", as seen [here](http://www.startwright.com/words1.htm), but it's not listed in a dictionary.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a word that means `a word-describing noun`, and there's no such thing in English. The `nymonym` in Hellion's comment is probably the closest you can get, though even that doesn't cover everything

Comment: @blgt I was beginning to think `nymonym` was the answer. Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't cover everything?"

Comment: While there's no explicit definition in the provided link, it doesn't seem to include parts of speech such as nouns

Comment: @blgt The parenthetical phrase says a `nymonym` is "a word about words." That's the closest thing we get to a definition.

Comment: @Hellion You should post nymonym as an answer.

Comment: @acbabis done.  :-)

Comment: With 'nymonym' luckily there's no other word for itself; 'nymonym' is a nymonym. So it's not turtles all the way down, instead the buck stops here.

Comment: It's a lexicon or dictionary. It's a word that describes words :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The neologistic *nymonym* has been used in what I believe is exactly the sense you are seeking, at [StartWright.com](http://www.startwright.com/words1.htm).  It has not yet made it into any dictionaries that I can find, but its meaning is readily derivable: since *nym* is the root for "word" a *nymonym* is therefore a "word word", or a word about words.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the term meta when describing it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage

Answer (score -1):

In lingustics, it is **Lexis**

A lexis (from the Greek: λέξις "word") is the total word-stock or lexicon having items of lexical

Please check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexis_(linguistics)) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_item)

Comment: Lexis is the vocabulary of a language. It doesn't define a word.

Comment: @emanen  Vocabulary is different. Please check http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/difference-between-lexicon-and-dictionary

Comment: That is a different discussion. Check here: http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/lexisterm.htm

Answer (score -4):

I would vote for "Wordsense - it's like commonsense, but dealing with semantics....?

Go to:  The 5 W's: http://m-howell.com/wordpress/ for more information.

Comment: Please don't suggest neologisms.

Comment: @MattЭллен The most upvoted answer is a neologism. What if there isn't a good answer that isn't a neologism?

Comment: The most upvoted answer is a word that's already in use but hasn't yet featured in a dictionary. It's not quite the same. If there isn't a good answer that isn't a neologism, then maybe the question doesn't have a single word answer.