# What do you call the set of ngrams?

Tags: collocation, lexicon, frequency-analysis

A **lexicon** is a **list of words** that belong to a particular language ([see this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34974/61416)).

Is there a name for "**the set of all ngrams**" ? I mean the set of all consecutive words ([collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) and higher order combinations) that have be written in a given language, such as all the sequences we can find in the Google Ngram Viewer.

For example, the 5-gram dataset in English (5 consecutive words) has millions++ of unique sequences and I can't find a word to name this whole set. If I had to convey the concept, I would go for something like "*word sequentome*" to mimic the *[transcriptome](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/transcriptome-296/)*, or *meta-lexicon* that adds an extra-layer to the lexicon - but there must be a word for that.

Comment: This paper here (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S095741741830143X) seems to refer to what you're looking for as an "n-gram lexicon" -- unless I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: @General Poxter  - Seems like you found a Needle here ! Just great thanks.

Comment: Hello, Marsei. How is n-gram defined, precisely? You specify (paraphrasing) 'loose collocations and more cohesive strings', but have you an authority licensing this? Is 'tame bagpipes' a 2-gram given it appears in passages such as 'Shoots and Ladders is pretty tame. Bagpipes and nursery rhymes gets people interested' on the internet? 'Google ngrams' searches for all such strings, and Wikipedia seems to regard them as n-grams.

Answer (score -1):

**No**. Few enough people talk about a lexicon, and most language users don't care about how many letters are in a word (remember that speech historically comes before writing).
I don't see why there would be a word for this, and (having done an English degree and spent years playing Scrabble) I haven't come across one.

Comment: It's likely to have technical applications in contexts like natural language processing and other aspects of computational linguistics, so unless you are involved in those areas, your ignorance isn't proof of anything.

Comment: whereas your ignorance ("it's likely..." -- and incorrectly assuming that I have no NLP background) means a whole lot.  This place is about English usage, not about technical data dictionaries.